# Why is System.Text.Json located in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite? Error after I removed it I received an error

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

I removed from

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite

from my .csproj to replace it with

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

but after I removed it, I lost my reference to

> JsonSerializer class or Json ref

in

> System.Text.Json;

Why, and how can I get it back without installing the sqlite package?

Comment: From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-overview: *The library is built-in as part of the .NET Core 3.0 shared framework.  For other target frameworks, install the [System.Text.Json NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json) package. The package supports: NET Standard 2.0 and later versions...*  - is that all you need to know?  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Hi dbc. Not really, my concern/question is why did removing the Sqlite package, remove the Json package. I added the package back and now I have the Json library again. I'm using core 3.1. Why would the Sqlite package have/contain the Json serializer package!? And why wasn't it there to begin with? It says it's built in, but it gets removed when removing other packages!!!!!?

Comment: *I'm using core 3.1* - but you tagged this [tag:.net-standard-2.0], might you update your tags then?  If you're targeting .Net Core 3.1 it does seem strange that `System.Text.Json` was removed, I don't know why that might be happening.

Comment: I added sqlite back and the error went away. So I then removed it again, because I don't need sqlite anymore (using sqlserver) and then added the package System.Text.Json and I moved on...